Migrating MDriven solution to .NET Standard 2.0, including WebProviders?
We have an old solution that has one ASP.NET MVC 5 app that targets .NET Framework 4.7.2, and one WinForms app that also targets .NET Framework 4.7.2. The soution has a separate project for the model and one for the EcoSpace. These are also built and published internally as NuGet packages.
Now, we want to author a new app using our Model + EcoSpace Nuget packages, but the new app should target .NET 8. So we need to migrate those two projects to .NET Standard 2.0.
I've noticed that there are separate MDriven packages for .NET Standard, but our model includes the EcoWebProviders package, and I don't see any .NET Standard variant of it.
How should we proceed?
